# Unix mv command: Incorrectly type '.:' instead of target folder

Tags: unix, mv

While moving folders using the mv command (Unix) I incorrectly specified the target folder of the copy with `.:` instead of the path I wanted.

meaning instead of:

```
mv ./folder/to/move/ ./target/folder/
```

I typed:

```
mv ./folder/to/move/ .:
```

The command moved the folder somewhere. How can I find this location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command created a folder named `.:` in the current folder. 
As the name starts with a `.` it's invisible with a simple `ls` check.
A `cd .:` move you to it.

(Note: I used `find` to look for the folder and found a match with a folder name `.:`.)

Comment: You could also `ls -la` and look (vgrep) for it.